# Google Maps not zooming to my current location

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3

I have to plot multiple pins in a Google Map view, and then zoom to the user's current location. Pins are plotted successfully but not zoomed to current location. Any help would be appreciated

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if (self.googleMapsView == nil) {
            self.googleMapsView =  GMSMapView(frame: self.mapViewContainer.frame)
            self.view.addSubview(self.googleMapsView)
            print(AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().mapArray)
              googleMapsView.clear()
            for i in 0...AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().mapArray.count - 1 {
               let lon =  Double ((AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().mapArray[i]["lon"] as? String)!)
                let lat =  Double ((AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().mapArray[i]["lat"] as? String)!)
                let tit = AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().mapArray[i]["location"] as? String
                locateWithLongitude(lon: lon!,andLatitude: lat! ,andTitle: tit!)

            }




            let marker = GMSMarker(position: AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().myLocation)
            let camera  = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().myLocation.latitude, longitude: AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().myLocation.longitude, zoom: 11)
            self.googleMapsView.camera = camera
            marker.title = AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().sublocality
            marker.map = self.googleMapsView
            self.googleMapsView.animate(to: camera)

        }
    }




func locateWithLongitude(lon: Double, andLatitude lat: Double, andTitle title: String) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
            let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
            let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
            let camera  = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lon, zoom: 0)
            self.googleMapsView.camera = camera
            marker.title = title
           marker.map = self.googleMapsView
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain what are you trying? because you are calling zoom several times as I can see, if you can explain a little is more easy for us to help you

Comment: I have plot multiple annoation on map and zoom to current location

Comment: You need only zoom to curren location or to several locations one before another?

Comment: no only current location

Answer (score 0):

Your zoom is set to 0, increase it to 15/16 like bellow.

```
let camera  = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lon, zoom: 16)
```